# TFS2015 - The build fails because access to Microsoft.Build.Tasks.CodeAnalysis.dll 'is denied.

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs-2015

I periodically have the following error during builds:
Access to the path 'C:\Builds\4\MyApp\Sources\External\Packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0\tools\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.CodeAnalysis.dll' is denied.
This is not blocking because the next build has been working. But in the case of continuous integration, it is very penalizing.
My configuration: TFS2015/VS2015 and the build server is Windows Server 2008 R2
Any help would be highly appreciatable.

Comment: Do you use XAML build or new build system? Do you use Nuget to restore packages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You could try to clean the cache folder on your build agent machine. The folder path is: `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\x.0\Cache`.
2. Clean the build directory on your build agent machine.
3. If you use old XAML build, [migrate to new build system](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/build/migrate-from-xaml-builds?view=vsts).
4. Make sure you [use Nuget to restore packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore). NuGet Package Restore installs all a project's dependencies as listed in either the project file or `packages.config`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Effectively, clearing the repository folder of the build resolves problems. I also think that the error was due to msbuild.exe still running even after builds were completed. In another case I had to delete the processes in the task manager.

Comment: AppData will be in hidden so just don't forget to see hidden item if you do not see AppData